# Swift: Only segue from certain rows/sections in a table

Tags: ios, swift

I have two sections in my table, "Tracks Played" and "Up Next". When the user taps on a song from "Up Next", they transition back to the same view controller, but the song they tapped is now in the "Tracks Played" section and the "Up Next" section has different songs depending on the song they tapped. My problem is that the user should not be able to tap songs that are in the "Tracks Played" section, only songs in the "Up Next" section. I have removed selection animations and disclosure indicators from the "Tracks Played" section, but tapping a song from "Tracks Played" still triggers a segue. My current band-aid solution is to transition to the same screen again, but this is quite hacky and if the user wants to go back then they have to go back through the identical view which they came from.

In Summary, how do I disable segues for certain sections in a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `UITableViewDelegate` method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath?
```

This method is executed after the user taps a cell in the table but immediately before it is selected. It gives you a chance to work out if the cell should actually be allowed to be selected. If you choose 'no', return nil and the cell will not be selected.

Use your app logic in this method to determine which rows should not allow selection/segue and return nil when you shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

For that you can perform segues when you want by programmatically

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "YourseguesId", sender: nil)
```

And Another way is that your can put your logic in shouldPerformSegue method and return true if your want to open screen or return false if dont want to open screen

```
override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool
{
   // Put your logic here where you want to perform Segue or not
    return YES
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to disconnect your segue's source as tableview cell, reconnect that segue to view controller as source, and call `performSegueWithIdentifier` when you tap your table's cell.

```
// MARK: UITableViewDelegate
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    if shouldPerformSegue(indexPath.section) { //your logic
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("your segue id", sender: cell)
    }
}
```